# nodejs. не получается загрузить скрипты и стили

Tags: node.js, express

Всем привет,

у меня такая проблема, не получается загрузить файлы стилей и скриптов на сервере.

файловое древо:

```
--bootstrap
--css
--js
---libs
```

в консоли выдает ошибку

```
localhost/:8 GET http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 
localhost/:9 GET http://localhost:3000/css/template.css 
localhost/:11 GET http://localhost:3000/js/libs/jquery%201.12.5-pre.js 
localhost/:12 GET http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js 
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular.min.js 
localhost/:15 GET http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular-route.min.js 
localhost/:16 GET http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular-resource.min.js 
localhost/:17 GET http://localhost:3000/js/libs/angular-cookies.min.js 
localhost/:19 GET http://localhost:3000/js/app.js 
localhost/:20 GET http://localhost:3000/js/controllers.js 
localhost/:21 GET http://localhost:3000/js/directives.js 404 (Not Found)
```

код server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('TestApp'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/TestApp'));

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('working on', server.address().port);
});
```

провобал так прописать, но тогда возникает другая проблема, и так же ничего не подгружает

```
app.get('*', function(req,res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете `express.static`.

Вызывая:

```
app.use(express.static('TestApp'));
```

вы указываете Express.js, что все статические файлы нужно искать в каталоге `TestApp`, но судя по вашему дереву каталогов - это не так.

Я бы советовал вам переместить все ваши статические файл (отдаваемые клиентам) в один каталог верхнего уровня, например так:

```
node_modules/
static/
    bootstrap/
    css/
    js/
        libs/
    index.html
server.js
```

Тогда код `server.js` может иметь вид:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('static'));

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('working on', server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: спасибо, все заработало, я вот просто самостоятельно изучаю не все понятно, можете посоветовать что можно почитать?

Comment: На мой взгляд, официальной документации по express вполне достаточно.